# Replace by NaN if string contains digits or symbols

Tags: python, pandas, regex, replace

I have a dataframe and I need to identify values that contain numbers or symbols in order to eliminate them. Only letters and spaces are allowed. The size of the dataframe is quite big and what I am trying doesn't result in anything:

```
df.NAME=df.NAME.replace(r"(/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/)",np.nan,regex=True)
```

Any suggestions?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to only keep items with letters and spaces only, you need a silution based on [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), not `replace`:

```py
df['NAME']=df[df['NAME'].str.contains(r"^[a-zA-Z\s]*$", regex=True)]
```

That will keep all those items in `NAME` column that only contain ASCII letters or/and whitespaces.

To support any Unicode letters, you'd need

```py
df['NAME']=df[df['NAME'].str.contains(r"^(?:[^\W\d_]|\s)*$", regex=True)]
```

where `(?:[^\W\d_]|\s)` matches either any Unicode letter (together with most diacritics) or a whitespace char.